# Note that or noted that

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is grammatical?

> Note that we have previously discussed about this.

or

> Noted that we have previously discussed about this.

Note to Myself: First one is correct (by StoneyB)

Comment: It's unclear. There are four sentences. Which ones you are asking? As a set or all individually?

Comment: @MaulikV to make it clear I delete two of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that we have previously discussed this.

Here *note* is a finite verb in the imperative: the subject is always understood to be *you*. You call upon the reader to observe that the matter has already been discussed.

> Noted that we have previously discussed this.

*Noted* may be understood as either a finite past-tense form or a non-finite past participle. In both cases, the  sentence is defective:

- If *noted* is a finite verb, the sentence is missing its subject—*who* observed that we have already discussed this?
- If *noted* is a non-finite past participle there is neither a subject nor the finite verb which a sentence requires. This can only be treated as some sort of subordinate clause. But the clause cannot be employed  as an adjectival past participle modifying some other sentence consituent, because such a constituent has to be the object of the non-finite verb, and you have already supplied that object: *that we have previously discussed this*.

  In fact, this usage can **only** be construed as a fragmentary comment (perhaps written in the margin?), not as either a sentence or a part of a sentence. It is not something which can properly appear in formal discourse.

Comment: So using "note that" would be grammatically correct, but "noted that" is not, in this case?

Comment: @william007 Right. You can say *I/you/he/she/it/they noted that ... * or *It has been noted that ...*, but bare *noted that ...* is just, well, a note to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First, the word *discuss* includes *about* so no need to repeat it! You discuss the project, you don't discuss about the project.

Now, which one is correct. Both mean different.

> *"Note that we have previously discussed this."* - you are telling someone to note that the discussion has happened. 
>   *"Noted that we have previously discussed this."* - you are taking a note (in affirmation) that yes, it has been discussed earlier.

Comment: RE: _You discuss the project, you don't discuss about the project._ That's true, although it might be worth mentioning that you **can** have a _discussion about the project._